# Replace all tags with &lt; within <pre> tags?

Tags: php, syntax-highlighting

I have a script, which uses http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/ for highlighting XML code samples.
There is a bug in Highlighter, which causes all XML tags to become lowercase. It doesn't happen, when tags are written in the format `&lt;TAG> instead of <TAG>.`

I need a way to replace all tags between `<pre> and </pre>` this way.

Any ideas?

Comment: Ahem, you _do_ realize that such "tags" are not valid xml tags? That this is the reason why the highlighter leaves them alone?

Comment: Have you [read the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)

Comment: Oh, and... the xml standard suggests lowercase for xml tags...

Comment: I know, that it is wrong, but our systems returns these.